# Subclassing UITextfield in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am currently initializing quite a few properties in my view controller, but it just feels very, very messy. I have been creating `UITextField` like:

```
lazy var passwordTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 30))
        textField.leftView = paddingView
        textField.leftViewMode = .always
        textField.placeholder = "Password"
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.none
        textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Password", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray])
        textField.tintColor = UIColor.white
        textField.borderStyle = .none
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 0.7
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.textColor = UIColor.white
        return textField
    }()
```

I have about 5 of these per `UIViewController`. I would like to create a `UITextField` class that is basically a factory that pumps out custom UITextFields. How might I accomplish this?

Comment: Looks like it's `UITextField` not `UILabel`, please confirm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclassing any item is quite easy. Just do something like

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        textFieldSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        textFieldSetup()
    }

    private func textFieldSetup() {
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 30))
        leftView = paddingView
        leftViewMode = .always
        ...
        ...
        //Add the common properties here that you want replicated for every instance
        ...
        ...
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 0.7
        textColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

Then, you can create an instance of `MyTextField` instead of `UITextField`

```
var passwordTextField: MyTextField!
```

Comment: Now is it advised to use the property without assigning it as weak? Would this not create a retain cycle?

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass `UITextField` like,

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.customInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.customInit()
    }

    func customInit(){
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 30))
        self.leftView = paddingView
        self.leftViewMode = .always
        self.placeholder = "Password"
        self.isSecureTextEntry = true
        self.autocorrectionType = .no
        self.autocapitalizationType = .none
        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Password", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray])
        self.tintColor = .white
        self.borderStyle = .none
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.7
        self.textColor = .white
    }
}
```

To use the custom label or text field,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myCustomTextField: CustomTextField!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create extension for textfield like,

```
extension UITextField {

    func setLeftPaddingPoints(_ amount:CGFloat){
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: amount, height: self.frame.size.height))
        self.leftView = paddingView
        self.leftViewMode = .always
    }
    func setRightPaddingPoints(_ amount:CGFloat) {
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: amount, height: self.frame.size.height))
        self.rightView = paddingView
        self.rightViewMode = .always
    }
}
```